# drivers license test questions using python

Tags: python

The local Driver's License Office has asked you to write a program that grades the written portion of the driver's license exam. The exam has 20 multiple choice questions. Here are the correct answers: 1.A 2.C 3.A 4.A 5.D 6.B 7.C 8.A 9.C 10.B 11.A 12.D 13.C 14.A 15.D 16.C 17.B 18.B 19.D 20.A

your program should store these correct answers in a list. The program should read the student's answers for each of the 20 questions from a text file and store the answers in another list. After the students's answers have been read from the file, the program should display a message indicating whether the student passed or failed the exam. The student must correctly answer 15 of the 20 questions to pass. It should then display the total number of correctly answered questions, the total number of incorrectly answered questions, and a list showing the question numbers of the incorrectly answered questions.

If anyone can give me some input on what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
def main():
    corr_ans_list = ["A", "C", "A", "A", "D", "B",
                     "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "D",
                     "C", "A", "D", "C", "B", "B",
                     "D", "A"]
    user_ans_list = []
    corr_count = 0
    incorr_count = 0
    num_questions = 20

    infile = open('user_answers.txt', 'r')

    user_ans_list = infile.readlines()

    infile.close()

    index = 0

    print("Q\tocrr\tYour\tStatus")
    print("#\tAnswer\tAnswer\n--------------------------")

    while index < 20:                 
    print(str(index+1) + "\t" + corr_ans_list[index]+ "\t" + user_ans_list[index],end="\t" )
        if user_ans_list[index].strip() == corr_ans_list[index]:
            corr_count += 1
            index += 1
            print("               Correct")
        else:
            incorr_count += 1
            index += 1
            print("               Wrong")

    percent_corr = (corr_count/num_questions) * 100
    percent_corr_fmt = format(percent_corr, ".1f")
    print("Grade : ", corr_count , "/", num_questions, " = ",
          percent_corr_fmt, sep="")

    if percent_corr >= 75:
        print("Congratulations!! You passed the exam")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you did not pass the exam")


main()
```

The final answer I have gotten.

```
Q   Corr    Your    Status
#   Answer  Answer
--------------------------
1   A   A
                   Correct
2   C   C
                   Correct
3   A   A
                   Correct
4   A   B
                   Wrong
5   D   D
                   Correct
6   B   B
                   Correct
7   C   C
                   Correct
8   A   A
                   Correct
9   C   C
                   Correct
10  B   B
                   Correct
11  A   B
                   Wrong
12  D   D
                   Correct
13  C   C
                   Correct
14  A   A
                   Correct
15  D   D
                   Correct
16  C   B
                   Wrong
17  B   B
                   Correct
18  B   B
                   Correct
19  D   B
                   Wrong
20  A   A
                   Correct
Grade : 16/20 = 80.0
Congratulations!! You passed the exam
```

Comment: You need to know python to get a drivers licence? Where do you live?

Comment: @Pradhan its just the way of question

Comment: *What* error are you getting?

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: New error in line 30 "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need this:

```
user_ans = infile.readline()   # readline reads only one line of a flle
user_ans_list.append(user_ans)
```

use `readlines` will give you list of all lines in a file

```
user_ans_list = infile.readlines()
```

here you will need `strip`. as readlines take line with newline character

```
if user_ans_list[index].strip() == corr_ans_list[index]:
```

to fix ZeroDivisionError: division by zero". this error is raise when a number is divided by zero.

```
num_questions = 10
```

put this above while:

```
print("Q\tocrr\tYour\tStatus")
```

your while shouil look like this:

```
while index < 20:                 
    print(str(index+1) + "\t" + correct_ans_list[index]+ "\t" + user_ans_list[index],end="\t" )
    if user_ans_list[index] == corr_ans_list[index]:
        corr_count += 1
        index += 1
        print("Correct")
    else:
        incorr_count += 1
        index += 1
        print("Wrong")
```

Comment: Only problem I have now is in line 30 and the error is "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero"

Comment: you have given num_questions = 0 ??

Comment: num_questions = 20 i think

Comment: alright it is all figured out now. One last question, how would I show a list showing the wrong answers

Comment: I am getting this after running the module.                     Q corr Your Status
# Answer Answer
--------------------------
Grade : 16/20 = 80.0
Congratulations!! You passed the exam

Comment: another error is now coming up in line 22 "NameError: name 'i' is not defined"

Comment: replace i with `index`

Comment: Thank You for all the help! I understand more from your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_candidate_answers():
    outfile=open('answers.txt','r')
    answer_list=outfile.read().split()
    return answer_list

def correct_answers():
    correct_list= ['A','C','A','A','D','B','C','A','C','B','A','D','C','A','D','C','B',\ 'B','D','A']
    return correct_list

def result(answer_list,correct_list):
    count=0
    wrong_answers=[]
    for i in range(20):
        if answer_list[i]==correct_list[i]:
            count+=1
        else:
            count+=0
            wrong_answers.append(i)
    if count<15:
        print("Failed")
    else:
        print("Passed")
    print("Number of Correct answers: ", count)
    print("Number of Incorrect answers: ",20-count)
    print("Incorrect answers list is: ", wrong_answers)

answers=read_candidate_answers()
correct=correct_answers()
output=result(answers,correct)
```

Comment: You need to covert the file you are reading to list(using .split() method) to compare it with correct answers' list.
Also you need not find the percentage- the question does not ask percentage but just the count. 
Please refer to the solution posted above my me.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `user_ans_list` only has one member, because you only read in one line from the file.